# Bluetooth Low Energy - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I've been struggling with this for the past few hours and searching SO before I don't think I can find a way to sovle my problem. Basically I'm trying to use Context inside of the Fragment extension and it's giving me errors I've pasted the full code here in this gist

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/eWizardII/9d2fc646c10eaf6379a1)

From what I found on SO it sounds like this happens when there is null for Context, but I don't understand how to fix it.

LogCat:

```
> 06-18 10:20:08.972    5718-5718/com.aparosecurity.kblock W/dalvikvm﹕
> threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41625898)
> 06-18 10:20:08.992    5718-5718/com.aparosecurity.kblock
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.aparosecurity.kblock.ImageFragment.onCreate(ImageFragment.java:77)
>             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
>             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
>             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:834)
>             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:841)
>             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
>             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
>             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
>             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
>             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
>             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is appreciated.

The specific lines which are failing, the error occurs when mContext is used.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    mHandler = new Handler();

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

}
```

Comment: You really need to show the code for your onCreate method and indicate which is line 77.  Also read this on fragments and their lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

Comment: It's in the gist file - but I will pull it out, thanks I'll look at that link too.

Comment: Is `mContext` initialized? Looks like it is `null`

Comment: Fragments have to get their context from the activity (getActivity()) but can only do that when the fragment is attached to an activity.  Are you setting mContext in your fragment's onAttach method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `mContext` and it is null. Invoking a method on null reference causes the NPE.

In a fragment, use `getActivity()` to get a reference to the hosting activity that can be used as a `Context`. (Caveat: Only when attached to an activity. Works in `onCreate()` which comes after `onAttach()`.)

So, replace

```
mContext.getSystemService()
```

with

```
getActivity().getSystemService()
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have fixed the issues I've been having.